# Android : How to set the selector xml in such condition?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, selector, android-xml

In ImageView i have set the rounded border as like below:

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/twsbiLogoButton"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:src="@drawable/tp_twsbi_logo"
                    android:background="@drawable/logo_layout_border"></ImageView>
```

where background is xml file like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke 
        android:width="1dip" 
        />
    <solid 
        android:color="#3D2A1D"/>
    <corners 
        android:radius="20sp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

But i also want to give the selector to that imageview so how it is podssible ?

Answer (score 1):

are you talking about focus?

```
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: No Dear, I mean normly we put the selector on button background that take effect while we presed it. as same i want it for my imageView. that should change the colour if user pressed on it.

Answer (score 1):

We can do by using **LayerList** Just create one more xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke 
        android:width="1dip" 
        />
    <solid 
        android:color="#3D2A1D"/>
    <corners 
        android:radius="20sp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
</item>
```

/* Now add more items which you use in the selector */

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/postbutton_press" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/postbutton_press" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/postbutton_normal"/>

</layer-list>
```

Now add this drawable to your **android:background** of the Imageview / Button. 
I didn't test this. Guess it would work! Fingers crossed! :)...

Comment: Ha ha ha. . .  ok let me try it.